# Check if two arrays are equal key value with same name

Tags: php, compare

I have two arrays:

```
$arr1 = array(
    1 => 250,
    2 => 325,
    3 => 741,
    4 => 690
);

$arr2 = array(
    1 => 110,
    2 => 740,
    3 => 1200,
    4 => 500
);
```

I want to check if all `$arr2` values are less than `$arr1` values

There are now 2 keys `[1] + [4]` its less than `$arr1` keys `[1] + [4]`

**Without a foreach loop**, I want to return true or false if any key from `$arr2` is less than the same key from `$arr1`.

Comment: Sorry your question is unclear. Would like to attempt. What's the expected output?

Comment: Does the array always only have 4 keys?

Comment: Did you mean any key from `$arr2` is less than the same key from `$arr1`?

Comment: yes always only 4 keys

Comment: Don't Panic yes your are right

Comment: I think use of array map will be the better option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.

```
$result = (bool) array_filter(array_map(function($a, $b){
    return $b < $a;
}, $arr1, $arr2));
```

The inner `array_map` returns `true` or `false` based on the comparison of corresponding values of `$arr1` and `$arr2`. Then the outer `array_filter` reduces the result to only include `true` values. Casting the result to boolean will yield `true` if all values in `$arr2` are greater than or equal to the corresponding `$arr1` values (because `array_filter` will return an empty array), and `false` if any of them are less.

Keep in mind that avoiding a foreach loop is *not* more efficient for something like this. Both the `array_map` and `array_filter` functions will iterate the entire array they are given. If you use a `foreach` instead, you can break out of the loop as soon as you find an element that meets the condition you're looking for, which in this case would be the first iteration of the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that does not use foreach() but most of us would use an iterator to work with array elements.  You could use for() or while() loops, too.

```html
<?php // demo/temp_samer.php
/**
 * Compare array elements
 *
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45422576/check-if-two-arrays-are-equal-key-value-with-same-name
 */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo '<pre>';


$arr1=array('1'=>250,'2'=>325,'3'=>741,'4'=>690);
$arr2=array('1'=>110,'2'=>740,'3'=>1200,'4'=>500);

if ($arr2[1] < $arr1[1]) echo PHP_EOL . "KEY 1 IS LOWER IN THE SECOND ARRAY";
if ($arr2[2] < $arr1[2]) echo PHP_EOL . "KEY 2 IS LOWER IN THE SECOND ARRAY";
if ($arr2[3] < $arr1[3]) echo PHP_EOL . "KEY 3 IS LOWER IN THE SECOND ARRAY";
if ($arr2[4] < $arr1[4]) echo PHP_EOL . "KEY 4 IS LOWER IN THE SECOND ARRAY";
```

Answer (score -1):

This shows a way of thinking about the problem.
https://iconoun.com/demo/temp_samer.php

```html
<?php // demo/temp_samer.php
/**
 * Compare array elements
 *
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45422576/check-if-two-arrays-are-equal-key-value-with-same-name
 */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo '<pre>';


$arr1=array('1'=>250,'2'=>325,'3'=>741,'4'=>690);
$arr2=array('1'=>110,'2'=>740,'3'=>1200,'4'=>500);

foreach ($arr2 as $key => $value)
{
    if ($value < $arr1[$key]) echo PHP_EOL . "KEY $key IS LOWER IN THE SECOND ARRAY";
}
```

Comment: Why do you not want to use foreach()?  It's a very convenient way of matching up the array keys, so we can test the values.

Comment: Op stated pretty clearly in the question "Without a foreach loop" so this does not answer the question.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that.  Was it edited or am I just missing a brain cell?

Comment: It was there initially, and became a bit more clear after @GrumpyCrouton edited. But, you are here answering PHP questions with us, so the brain cells definitely are a concern regardless.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Just don't panic about missing brain cells ;)